# How to trigger TS in VS Code to reload types for a package?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've created an internal tool that lets you preview changes to an npm package in a consumer application by starting a watch and copying all files into node_modules of the consumer application.

Everything works great except that TS in VS Code doesn't react to the new .d.ts files that are copied. If I restart the TS server or open the .d.ts file in VS Code it gets reloaded, but I want TS to pick it up automatically.

I've tried touching package.json in node_modules as well as the package.json in node_modules without any effect.

How can I trigger the language server in VS Code to reload the types?